# How to convert the following C++ code to C#

Tags: c#, c++

```
1.    sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), [](Point2f lhs, Point2f rhs) { return lhs.x<rhs.x; } );
2.    sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.begin()+2, [](Point2f lhs, Point2f rhs) { return lhs.y<rhs.y; });
3.    sort(arr1.begin()+2, arr1.end(), [](Point2f lhs, Point2f rhs) { return lhs.y<rhs.y; });
```

I'm attempting to sort an array of points (`top-left --> bottom-left --> top-right --> bottom-right`). I'd like to convert the above to C# but I'm unsure how to accomplish the above. I have done the following so far:

```
var sortedArr1 = arr1.OrderBy(r => r.X).ThenBy(r=>r.Y).ToList();
```

Which I believe accomplishes statements 1 and 2, but doesn't solve the last statement.

[EDIT]
Based on the comments below I have added a snippet from source code.

```
 public List<Point2d> DetectCorners(Mat src)
    {
        var lines = src.HoughLines(1, Cv2.PI / 180, 50, 0, 0);
        Mat labels = new Mat();
        Mat centers = new Mat();
        List<Point2f> data = new List<Point2f>();
        for (uint i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            float rho = lines[i].Rho;
            float theta = lines[i].Theta;
            float x = rho * (float)Math.Cos(theta);
            float y = rho * (float)Math.Sin(theta);
            data.Add(new Point2f(x, y));
        }

        Cv2.Kmeans(InputArray.Create(data), 4, labels,
            new TermCriteria(CriteriaType.Eps & CriteriaType.Count, 10, 1.0), 5, KMeansFlags.PpCenters, centers);
        List<Point2f> fourPoints = new List<Point2f>();
        List<Point2f> xyPoints = new List<Point2f>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            float x = centers.At<float>(i, 0);
            float y = centers.At<float>(i, 1);
            float rho = (float)Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            float theta = (float)Math.Atan2(y, x);

            xyPoints.Add(new Point2f(x, y));
            fourPoints.Add(new Point2f(rho, theta));
        }
        
        var sortedXyPoints = xyPoints.OrderBy(r => Math.Abs(r.Y / r.X)).ToArray();
        List<Point2d> ans = new List<Point2d>();
        for (uint i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            float x0 = sortedXyPoints[i].X;
            float y0 = sortedXyPoints[i].Y;
            for (uint j = 2; j < 4; j++)
            {
                float x1 = sortedXyPoints[j].X;
                float y1 = sortedXyPoints[j].Y;
                float x = (y0 * (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) - y1 * (x0 * x0 + y0 * y0)) / (y0 * x1 - x0 * y1);
                float y = (x0 * (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) - x1 * (x0 * x0 + y0 * y0)) / (y1 * x0 - x1 * y0);
                ans.Add(new Point2d(x, y));
            }
        }
        // order of points (top-left, bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right)
        var sortedAns = ans.OrderBy(r => r.X).ThenBy(r=>r.Y).ToArray();
        //TODO: convert sort(arr1.begin()+2, arr1.end(), [](Point2f lhs, Point2f rhs) { return lhs.y<rhs.y; }); to c#
        return new List<Point2d>(sortedAns);
    }
```

Comment: what is *"top-left, bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right"* supposed to mean?

Comment: The C++ code first sorts the whole array by x-coordinate, then the first 2 elements by y-coordinate, then all the other elements by y-coordinate. Are you sure it does what you want to do? In the general case this seems rather strange.

Comment: Have you tested this code?  If not, could you provide a C# [mcve].  This question does not need the `c++` tag.

Comment: Side note: this C++ code looks suspicious (algorithm). What this suppose to do?

Comment: What is the nature of `arr1`? What do we know about this array? Does it always have 4 elements, 2 of which have one value of X, and 2 have the another value?

Comment: Nothing really suspicious honestly. This is a snippet from an open-source c++ library that sorts a series of points. I'm just attempting to port it to c# which I have done, but I'm trying to get a better understanding of how this part could be ported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate the exact behavior you can use [`Array.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Collections_IComparer_) or [`List.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__) that takes a start and length of the range to sort. You will need to implement an [`IComparer<T>`](http://IComparer%3CT%3E) instead of using a delegate, but it is fairly trivial to make a implementation that takes a delegate to compare a property of the object. This should let you replicate the exact behavior:

```
public class KeyComparer<T, TKey> : IComparer<T> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TKey> selector;
    public KeyComparer(Func<T, TKey> selector) => this.selector = selector;
    public int Compare(T x, T y) => selector(x).CompareTo(selector(y));
}
...
var xComparer = new KeyComparer<Point, float>(p => p.X);
var yComparer = new KeyComparer<Point, float>(p => p.Y);

myList.Sort(xComparer);
myList.Sort(0, 2, yComparer);
myList.Sort(2, myList.Length -2, yComparer);
```

However, I would be very hesitant to just use such a solution without understanding why this is done. I would see if I could find the description of the implemented algorithm, and see if that matches the implementation, or look for other implementations and see if they uses the same kind of sorting.

Comment: Thanks JonasH, this is similar to the approached I have used since posting this question. I do have an understanding of what the algorithm is doing and why, but I do believe there is a better alternative which I'm working on now. Thank you very much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful tool for converting short snippets of codes like that.

Notice that the free edition limits output to 100 lines per file (no limit on the number of files).

visit:
https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/cplusplus_to_csharp_converter_details.html